# Change iPad keyboard by modifying system files

Tags: ios, ipad, windows, jailbreak

I want to access the iPad system files on my computer, so that I can modify them to change one of the iPad keyboards to support my language.

However, when I plug the iPad to my Windows 7 PC, Windows opens it as a storage device with only some wallpaper. I can't see any system files.

How do I access the system and content files for the iPad?

Comment: This doesn't sound like something Apple would let you do - has the iPad been jailbroken yet?

Comment: What is the language you need?

Answer (score 1):

A certain number of custom keyboards are available on the App Store... maybe this could be the easiest solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

To access the file system on an iPad you will need to jailbreak it. Then you can install ssh and use that to access the filesystem. [This guide](http://www.techtosh.com/ipad/how-to-access-ipad-file-system-via-ssh-on-windows-mac/) provides some details.

The reason that you aren't able to see the system files on the iPad when you simply connect it to your computer is because you aren't meant to. Apple hides all of the internal system details to keep the iPad a simple to use consumer device. Most people don't need to modify or even see the system files. Before heading straight for the system internals, consider there may be a simpler way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreak your iPad using http://evasi0n.com and you will have total access to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to jailbreak (which i recommend evasi0n.com for), and then you will probably want to download the cydia app called iFile. iFile allows you to view and edit a wide range of files directly from your iPad. It costs some money but it is worth it.

If you're looking for something free or need to manage the files from you computer i recommend PhoneBrowse by iMobie.com.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to add the keyboard for the desired language by enabling it within the Settings app. On your iPad, go to Settings app → General → Keyboard → Keyboards → Add New Keyboard..., and select the keyboard of your choice. Of late, iOS has evolved to include support for a wide variety of languages and this approach should be taken first.

The intended approach as discussed in the question is neither possible and straightforward, nor is it recommended for attempting to add support for a new language in your iPad keyboard. Also, it isn't advisable to jailbreak your iOS device just for the sake for changing keyboard language.

Additionally, starting with **iOS 8**, Apple has enabled support for 3rd-party keyboard apps. A lot of such apps are now available on the App Store, and you should be able to find the one that fits your requirements. Alternatively, you can also write your own keyboard app that best suits your needs.

You can Learn more about keyboard settings by reading this Apple Support article, [About the keyboards settings on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202178).